# calculate average height of students

Tags: python

I need help with my calAvgHeight. My addUser works. The problem with my calAvgHeight is that "total += float(info[1])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:"
and I don't know what to replace it with.

listOfStudentHeight.txt:

```
# CHITRA DEVI D/O SILVARAJAH        1.65
# MARSHEAL HOUDEL S/O MATHEWS JA    1.72
# MUHAMMAD AZLIE B ZULKIFLIE        1.68
# HO QIN YUAN MElVIN                1.69
# TENG YONG PENG DESMOND            1.76
# CHEONG LEE YEE                    1.59
# MUHAMMAD ZULFIKAR B ZAINAL        1.90
# ASYRAFIZWANI BTE ABDUL LATIFF 1.58
# HIE BAO XIN                       1.63
# MAK YU JIE                        1.67

class CalUtils:
        def __init__(self):
            self.names = []
            self.heights = []
            self.totalStudentHeight = 0
            self.totalStudentCount = 0

    def addUser(self):

        name = input("Please enter your name:")
        while True:
            try:
                height = input("Please enter your height:")
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("You have entered a non-numeric")

        f = open("listOfStudentHeight.txt", "a")
        f.write("\n" + name + "\t" + height)
        f = open("listOfStudentHeight.txt", "r")
        print(f.read())
        f.close()

    def calAvgHeight(self):

        names = []
        height = []
        total = 0
        with open("listOfStudentHeight.txt", "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                info = line.split("\t")
                names.append(info[0])
                height.append(info[1])
                total += float(info[1])
                print("The average height is " + str(round(total / len(names), 2)))
        f.close()


Person = CalUtils()
Person.addUser()
Person.calAvgHeight()
```

Comment: We don't have your txt so I am afraid we can not help properly. If I were you I'd print `info` line by line to see what's wrong.

Comment: You might need to do `line.strip().split('\t')` to remove the newline?

Comment: @Frightera the code itself seems to generate the file.

Comment: you probably incorrectly parse your txt file somehow, try debug and see what is the value of `info[1]` ?

Comment: 1) `f.write("\n" + name + "\t" + height)` makes your file start with an empty line, and that's how the code dies. It works with `f.write(name + "\t" + height + "\n")`

Comment: 2) `f = open("listOfStudentHeight.txt", "a")` appends to your existing file, so when it's broken (because there are empty lines in it here and there, it stays broken on subsequent runs

Answer (score 0):

It's not wise to use newline as a first character, your code crashes if starting with an empty file.

After chaning write line to `f.write(name + "\t" + height + "\n")`, you will see that the error is: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'name 200\n'`.

You can fix that by removing new line symbols using `strip()` function like this:

`info = line.strip().split()`.

Notice that `split()` doesn't take `"\t"` as arguments because `strip` removes all multiple spaces, leaving only single space character in your line.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't converted to float.

```py
            try:
                height = input("Please enter your height:")
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("You have entered a non-numeric")
```

You probably wanted to do this

```py
try:
    height = float(input("~~~~"))
except ValueError:
    ...
```

Therefore it fails to add float to string.

---

There's few thing I want to point out!

Sometimes it's better to write code again with newly learnt knowledge, rather than trying to understand what old code is doing.

For that reason I want you to know following 2 stuff (in case you don't know already):

### len() is fast for python built-in data structures

There's no reason to keep number of students on your own.

from Fluent python:

> But for built-in types like list, str, bytearray, and so on, the interpreter takes a short‐
> cut: the CPython implementation of len() actually returns the value of the ob_size
> field in the PyVarObject C struct that represents any variable-sized built-in object in
> memory. This is much faster than calling a method.

So just calling `len()` to your list/dict would be simpler, and most of cases, even faster than managing it manually.

### dictionaries are wonderful

When you have to keep name and height, it is better to use dictionary, aka `dict`.

```py
>>> nya = { "my cat": "persian", "your cat": "cheese tabi"}
>>> nya["my cat"]
'persian'

>>> nya["mamas cat"] = "tuxido"
>>> nya
{'my cat': 'persian', 'your cat': 'cheese tabi', 'mamas cat': 'tuxido'}
```

### pathlib.Path is a good, safe and user-friendly alternative

This is not strictly necessary, but is more convenient to have a instance of it rather than using `open("path", "a")` all time.

```py
>>> import pathlib
>>> text = pathlib.Path("text.txt")
>>> text
WindowsPath('text.txt')

>>> text.absolute()
WindowsPath('C:/Users/jupiterbjy/text.txt')

>>> text.write_text("Meow")
4

>>> text.read_text()
'Meow'

>>> with text.open("a") as fp:
...     fp.write("nya")

>>> text.read_text()
'Meownya'
```

---

Feel free to fiddling code again with above but if you really get stuck, feel free to peak this!

Updated code:

```
import pathlib
from typing import Dict


class CalUtils:
    def __init__(self, target_file_path: str):
        self.file = pathlib.Path(target_file_path)
        self.data: Dict[str, float] = {}

        # record size and sum for caching
        self._cached_size: int = 0
        self._cached_sum: float = 0

        # fill data
        try:
            self._read_written_data()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # file is not there yet, make one
            self.file.touch()

    def _read_written_data(self):
        # strip \n
        text = self.file.read_text().strip("\n")
        # parse already written data
        data = [line.split("\t") for line in text.split("\n")]

        for name, value_string in data:
            self.data[name] = float(value_string)

    @property
    def total_student_height(self):
        # check if size have changed compared to cached
        if self._cached_size != len(self.data):
            # if so, update cache
            self._cached_size = len(self.data)
            self._cached_sum = sum(self.data.values())

        return self._cached_sum

    @property
    def average_student_height(self):
        return self.total_student_height / len(self.data)

    def add_user(self):
        name = input("Please input your name: ")
        while True:
            try:
                height = float(input("Input your height: "))
            except ValueError:
                continue
            break

        # ensure this file to be closed after write
        # when using self.file.write() it is automatically closed without "with" clause
        with self.file.open("a") as fp:
            fp.write(f"{name}\t{height}\n")

        print(self.file.read_text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    util = CalUtils("height_data.txt")
    util.add_user()
```

output:

```
Please input your name: my neko
Input your height: 30
Nyarukoi    150.0
jupiter 170.0
my neko 30.0
```